# Piwik and Bootstrap modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, matomo

Does anybody know if piwik can track bootstrap modals or videos inside modals?

Our developement team has a piwik server set up and we're tracking every page on the site that we're currently working on. One main inquiry from our client is that they want to track how long a video is being played/looked into by the customers of the site.

I was checking the piwik server and at the moment it doesn't seem to be able to but maybe there's just a configuration issue that I need to set to view it. Anyone have experience on this that could enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track custom events with Piwik using [**Event Tracking**](http://piwik.org/docs/event-tracking/).

Basically it's a way to push any events of your choice, like "Video has been played", "Model has been opened", etc.

There's also a more advanced (and automated) solution: [**Content Tracking**](http://piwik.org/docs/content-tracking/).